# Is picture-in-picture the only way vLine does WebRTC?

Tags: webrtc, vline

I’ve integrated vLine into a test site and I’m noticing that it’s picture-in-picture. Is that the only way this works? Is there a way to have both streams separate?

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The picture-in-picture (PIP) mode occurs when you enable the [vLine UI widgets](https://vline.com/developer/docs/ui_widgets), specifically the [`uiVideoPanel` widget](https://vline.com/developer/docs/vline.js/vline.Options). Note that `"ui": true` enables all widgets, including the `uiVideoPanel` widget.

If you want to lay out the video streams in a custom manner, you can disable the `uiVideoPanel` widget and handle the [`mediaSession:addLocalStream` and `mediaSession:addRemoteStream` events](https://vline.com/developer/docs/vline.js/vline.MediaSession#events), where you can create the HTML `<video>` element with [`stream.createMediaElement()`](https://vline.com/developer/docs/vline.js/vline.MediaStream#createMediaElement). You can put the resulting `<video>` element in any div and adjust the layout with CSS.

The following snippet was lifted from the [vline-shell example](https://github.com/vline/shell-example):

```js
// $client is the vline.Client that you created with vline.Client.create()
$client.on('add:mediaSession', onAddMediaSession, self);

// callback on new MediaSessions
function addMediaSession_(mediaSession) {
  // add event handler for add stream events
  mediaSession.on('mediaSession:addLocalStream mediaSession:addRemoteStream', function(event) {
    // get the vline.MediaStream
    var stream = event.stream;

    // guard against adding a local video stream twice if it is attached to two media sessions
    if ($('#' + stream.getId()).length) {
      return;
    }

    // create video or audio element, giving it the the same id as the MediaStream
    var elem = $(event.stream.createMediaElement());
    elem.prop('id', stream.getId());

    // video-wrapper is the id of a div in the page
    $('#video-wrapper').append(elem);
  });
  // add event handler for remove stream events
  mediaSession.on('mediaSession:removeLocalStream mediaSession:removeRemoteStream', function(event) {
    $('#' + event.stream.getId()).remove();
  });
}
```